# simple rule for determining whether a (possibly random) sequence is "more" linear or geometric

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, regression

Suppose I have two series 
$$s_1 = (1,3,5,7,8,9,11)$$ 
$$s_2 = (1 \times 10^3, 1\times 10^2, 1\times 10^1, 0.5\times 10^1, 1\times 10^0, 1\times 10^{-1}, 1\times 10^{-2})$$
that are fairly obviously arithmetic and exponential, respectively. What's the best simple rule for classifying $s_1$ as "most likely a linear sequence" and $s_2$ as "most likely a geometric sequence"?

Is there something more efficient than regressing $s_1$ and $\log(s_1)$ on $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and comparing $R^2$ values (and similarly for $s_2$)? Is there a standard way to classify a sequence as "more geometric than linear" or vice versa? As in the case of 
$$
s_3 = (2,3,4,0.5 \times 10^1, 1 \times 10^1, 1 \times 10^2, 1 \times 10^3)
$$
How might we use arithmetic means and geometric means and variances?

Comment: are the sequences always strictly increasing in absolute value ? might try trend lines etc.  or at least seeing if the ratio is constant or falling in a strictly increasing case.

Comment: One simple way I could think up of, is to fit the data for an OLS, and then fit the $log$ of data for an OLS - to see which is better. Supposing they are increasing, we could let $x=1,2,3,4,5,6...$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: thanks, I was implicitly thinking strictly increasing (not even in magnitude) because we could always sort them. I like the point about looking at ratios -- how could we expand on this?

Comment: @YujieZha: thanks, yea, that was my first thought in the question. But is there a more succinct way of characterizing this?

Comment: if the sequence was linear the ratio would fall because because the constant amount of increase is a smaller percentage of the higher numbers.  if the ratio was growing then it might be exponential etc. not geometric.

Comment: Your idea of comparing correlation coefficients seems like the most natural way to do it. For $s_3$ the (linear) correlation is $0.663$ while the correlation of the log is $0.902$, so the sequence seems to be "more geometric than arithmetic".